# ¿como puedo postear a elastic search desde windows?

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

estoy desarrollando un sistemita que vaya posteando un log que tengo alojado en un servidor virtual, de momento solo postea los campos que no he definido y los postea de manera generica,el programa tambien lo parsea

```
clear-host
$contenido=Get-Content -Path \\"mi direccion host virtual"\log.txt |  Out-String

$obj = @()
foreach($line in ($contenido)){

    $nline = $line.Split(",") #-replace """",""
    $properties = @{
        'NombreTienda' = $nline[1]
        'NombreUsuario' = $nline[3]
        'NombreEquipo' = $nline[5]
        'VersionSO' = $nline[7]
        'Fecha' = $nline[9]
        'NumeroPOS'= $nline[11]
        'Accion' = $nline[13]
    }

    $obj += New-Object PSObject -Property $properties

}

$obj


Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri ""miuri"/logs" -Body '{"$obj"}' -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontre el error
cerrar

```
clear-host
```

$contenido=Get-Content -Path \"mirepositorio"\log.txt
foreach($line in ($contenido)){

```
$nline = $line.Split(",")
$properties = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    'NombreTienda' = $nline[1]
    'NombreUsuario' = $nline[3]
    'NombreEquipo' = $nline[5]
    'VersionSO' = $nline[7]
    'Fecha' = $nline[9]
    'NumeroPOS'= $nline[11]
    'Accion' = $nline[13]
}

$json = $properties | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri ""mikibana"\logs" -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'
```

}